# understanding LWE public key algorithm

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto, lwe

I'm trying to understand this LWE public key system

[image]

say I use matrix A = [[44, 73, 20, 54],[92, 19, 78, 22],[31, 34, 94, 29],[82, 32, 70, 68]]

q = 97

bit = 1

and secret key s: [56, 90, 0, 46]

and secret error vector e:[1, 0, -1, 0]

then B = As+e mod q is [73 17 18 27]

Bob's secret is [1, 0, 1, 1]

Bobby computes u = A*x mod q and get [21, 95,57, 26]

and v = B*x + bit*(q/2) mod q and get 69

Alice decrypts:

v-s*u = 69 - 58 = 11

11 is quiet far from q/2 = 48

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message bit should be just that, a *single bit*, and $v$ should be a single integer modulo $q$. I am not sure how you’re getting $v$ to be a vector. Note that $b^t x$ is an inner product (mod $q$), so it is also a single integer mod $q$.

Comment: @chrispiekert say I use matrix A = [[44, 73, 20, 54],[92, 19, 78, 22],[31, 34, 94, 29],[82, 32, 70, 68]]
q = 97
bit = 1
and secret key s: [56, 90, 0, 46]
and secret error vector e:[1, 0, -1, 0]

then B = As+e mod q is [73 17 18 27]

Bob's secret is [1, 0, 1, 1]

Bobby computes u = A*x mod q and get [21, 95,57, 26]
and v = B*x + bit*q/2 mod q and get 69
Alice decrypts:
 v-s*u = 69 - 58 = 11;

11 is quiet far from q/2 = 48

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What you call $B$ should be the row vector $b^t=s^t A+e^t$. It looks like you may be multiplying on the same side of $A$ for both $b$ and $u$, which will not work.